# Unusable app due to extremely slow queries

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

I'm facing a curious problem with database queries on Laravel.

I've implemented a dynamic query with query builder, using get parameters.

I've noticed certain queries were extremely slow, so I started debugging the generated sql from query builder and executed queries using raw sql statements, using DB::select( $sql ).

I did some research, and I'm aware of n+1 problem, but this isn't the case, because for debugging I simply used a controller action with DB::select( $sql ), and it doesn't show me any results. It showed me instead:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
> The proxy server could not handle the request GET /controller/action.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

The same query, with parameters that don't require a lot of database processing, runs fine using this method...

When I ran the problematic queries on MySQL Workbench, they took between 5 and 10 seconds to show results.

Further on my debugging, I manually created a PDO object in my action and executed the query. For my surprise, it took the same amount of time to run as with Workbench. I used hydrate method on the query results and the objects were rendered successfully on the view.

Next, I tried executing the queries with Laravel's PDO object, getting it with DB::getPdo(). The query wasn't processed, leading to Proxy Error again...

The problem is solved with a custom PDO object, but I don't like the idea of creating PDO objects, instead of using Laravel's one.

I don't understand why is this happening. Can it be related with database config, or Laravel's PDO object? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How long does it take for the proxy error to be thrown, is it the 5-10 seconds it would normally take to run the query or 30+ seconds?

Comment: It takes about 30+ seconds

Comment: Then it might be a timeout problem, as the default PHP `max_execution_time` setting for a script is 30 seconds. Laravel's query builder introduces some additional complexity on top of PDO which it uses internally, and your query complexity might create too much overhead. Your query seems to be the starting point of the issue, so I don't know if anyone can offer relevant advice without seeing what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this kind of issues are not fully related to slow or badly built queries but with MySQL settings not being properly managed.

MySql default settings are generic. There's a lot there that can be tweaked and fined tuned in order to improve significantly performance. Query cache, buffer, memory use, etc. There a lot that can be done.

Check this article: http://www.tecmint.com/mysql-mariadb-performance-tuning-and-optimization/

There are also specific tools for this purpose. Some have nice GUI but my favourite ones are based on the command line, like MyTop and MySQLTunner   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl